# Merging PDF files in a container (Azure Blob Storage)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a container in Azure blob storage where I have multiple single page pdf files. I want to merge them right there on container without downloading the files and merging them locally.
Is there a way to do it using `nodejs`?

I found a package called `easy-pdf-merge` in `npm` which merges the pdf but cannot find a way to merge them and store the file on azure container itself.

Thanks.

Comment: You won't be able to do without downloading the files locally. Alternatively, for minimal footprint at client, you would need a pdf merge library which can support stream as input and output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to interact with the files without downloading them somewhere; whether to your local machine or a server of some sort.

Is this a problem you could solve with an Azure Function utilising the Azure Storage REST API? It's feasible that you could access the necessary `.pdf` files, merge them, and then re-upload to the Azure blob storage container. If necessary, you could then also delete the single page `.pdf` files.